# Angular 6 data subscription issues with jQuery/javascript command

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an HTTP service that fetches data. In my component, I subscribe to this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.product = this.route.snapshot.data['product'];
    this.sectionService.getAll(this.product.id).subscribe( sections => {
      this.sections = sections;
    });
  }
```

and I have a ngFor loop in the component HTML that will create divs for each item.

```
<div class="col-md-9">      
   <div *ngFor="let section of sections" id="editor{{ section.id }}" contenteditable="true">
      {{ section.content }}
    </div>
    <!-- WYSIWYG -->
</div>
```

Now I have to run a javascript command on each one of those divs in order to enable an editor.

```
this.sections.forEach(element => {
    const editor = CKEDITOR.inline('editor' + element.id);
});
```

If I try to add my javascript line in the subscribe function, or the ngAfterViewInit() function it just doesn't work.

If I try to create a static array on ngOnInit() and then add my javascript code to ngAfterViewInit() it works.

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.product = this.route.snapshot.data['product'];
     this.sections = [ new Section(1, 'Hello', '<h1>test</h1>')];
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const editor = CKEDITOR.inline('editor1');
 }
```

How can I make this work for subscriptions?

Comment: Can you please show an example of the data inside  sections => {
      console.log(sections)

Comment: Why don't you move the `forEach` part into ngAfterViewInit? Your view is still not fully initialized in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Just a  thought : Create a wrapper component for initializing CKEditor. Something like <ckeditor-component [sections]="sections"></ckeditor -component> and pass the sections data from your current component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it in subscribe, the page may not have initialised. If you run it in ngAfterViewInit the HTTP request may not have completed. To ensure both are ready do this:

```
sections = []

ngOnInit() {
  this.product = this.route.snapshot.data['product'];
  this.sectionService.getAll(this.product.id).subscribe( sections => {
    this.sections = sections;
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.sections.length) {
      this.sections.forEach(element => {
        const editor = CKEDITOR.inline('editor' + element.id);
      });
      clearInterval(interval); // stop further executions of this code
    }
  }, 100) // check if sections are ready every 100ms
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding your javascript inside your subscribe, you'd have to get rid of the fat arrow notation and go back to normal function declaration inside subscribe and see if it works.

```
this.sectionService.getAll(this.product.id).subscribe(function(sections){
  this.sections = sections;
  this.sections.forEach(element => {
    const editor = CKEDITOR.inline('editor' + element.id);
  });
});
```